# Change array key value with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
  "id": "948",
  "app_id": "172",
  "image": "75733F51448032347-img.png",
  "type": "phone",
  "created_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:27",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:27"
},
{
  "id": "950",
  "app_id": "172",
  "image": "5813pKb1448032353-img.png",
  "type": "phone",
  "created_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:33",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:33"
},
{
  "id": "951",
  "app_id": "172",
  "image": "6864qUU1448032355-img.png",
  "type": "phone",
  "created_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:35",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-21 02:12:35"
}
```

I want to change all item image value. I am using this code but not work correctly

```
foreach($icon as $key => $value)
{
    $icon[2] = asset('uploads/apk-screen/'.$value);
    unset($icon[2]);
}
```

Please help me to find out what’s wrong I am doing.

Comment: what I understood, you are deleting the entry after assigning. Like: $icon[2] = asset('uploads/apk-screen/'.$value);, In this line you are assigning. and unset($icon[2]); in this line you are removing the second element.

Comment: your array looks to be json. Have you used `json_decode()` to create `$icon` first?

Comment: foreach($icon as $key => $value)
    {
        $existngValue=$icon[$key] = $value['image'];


        $newVal=asset('uploads/apk-screen/'.$existngValue);
        $icon[$key]['image'] = $newVal;

    }

also not work @DineshPatra

Comment: can you post the output of print_r($icon) completely.

Answer (score 1):

Finally its work

```
   foreach($icon as $key => $value)
    {
        $existngValue=$icon[$key]['image'] = $value['image'];


        $newVal=asset('uploads/apk-screen/'.$existngValue);
        $icon[$key]['image'] = $newVal;

    }
```